# Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert reactor.core.publisher.Mono<S> to reactor.core.publisher.Mono<? extends R>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two `Mono`-s and I'd like to return/throw an exception if one wasn't empty (the user already exists), or return a `Mono<User>` value based on the other one (copy settings and DTO data to User object). I wrote:

```
public Mono<User> registerUser(UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto) {
        Mono<Settings> settingsMono = settingsService.getSettings();
        Mono<User> dbUserMono = userRepository.findByEmail(userRegistrationDto.getEmail());
    return dbUserMono.map(dbUser -> Mono.error(new AlreadyRegisteredException())).or(
                settingsMono.map(
                    settings -> validateDtoAndCreateUser(userRegistrationDto, settings)
                ).flatMap(userRepository::save)
            );
```

The userRepository is a Spring Data ReactiveMongoRepository. The validateDtoAndCreateUser's signature is: `private User validateDtoAndCreateUser(UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto, SiteSettings siteSettings)`

Unfortunately at `userRepository::save` I'm getting:

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert reactor.core.publisher.Mono<S> to reactor.core.publisher.Mono<? extends R>
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I using a bad operator somewhere?

Comment: It would help if we had the declarations of the method you're writing and of the methods you're using.

Comment: Can you show the method signature?

Comment: @JBNizet edited, sorry!

Comment: And do you clearly know what the or operator does and if it suits you here?

Comment: @uneq95 actually no, I don't know how to chain these two together, just guessed that OR would work. Repository save returns Mono<User>.

Comment: Change the first map to flatMap and then try

Comment: @uneq95 I tried that, but then it says `Incompatible types.
Required:
Mono
<User>
Found:
Mono
<java.lang.Object>`

Comment: `Mono.<User>error(...)`. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#error-java.lang.Throwable-

Comment: @JBNizet with this and switchIfEmpty instead or, it works, thank you! If you convert this to an answer, I'll accept it. Uneq95 thank you too!

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
return dbUserMono.flatMap(dbUser -> Mono.<User>error(new AlreadyRegisteredException()))
                 .switchIfEmpty(settingsMono.map(
                    settings -> validateDtoAndCreateUser(userRegistrationDto, settings)
                  ).flatMap(userRepository::save));
```

Comment: This one says `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert reactor.core.publisher.Mono<S> to reactor.core.publisher.Mono<? extends User>`

Comment: Have you set the entity and its primary key in the repository?

Comment: UserRepository implements ReactiveMongoRepository<User,PrimaryKeyClass>

Comment: Yes: `public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String>`

Comment: The .flatMap(userRepository::save). With the Mono.<User>error which JB Nizet wrote it works, but I can't explain why.

Comment: both `flatMap` and `Mono.error` use generics to resolve their type, but `flatMap` deduces it from the right hand side while `error` deduces it from the left hand side. So when you use both, they can only infer you are dealing with an `Object`. Giving the compiler a hint by writing `Mono.<User>error` in turns lets `flatMap` deduce that it produces a `Mono<User>` itself.

Comment: @SimonBaslé thank You for the explanation! It's a honor to read your comment. :)